# WebGL GLSL Shader texture2D overrides other texture

Tags: react-native, expo, glsl, webgl

vertex shader

```
 attribute vec2 vertPosition;
    attribute vec2 vertTextCord;
    varying vec2 fragTextCord;
    void main(){
        fragTextCord = vertTextCord;
        gl_Position = vec4(vertPosition,0.0,1.0);
    }
```

fragment shader

```
        precision highp float;
    varying vec2 fragTextCord;
    uniform sampler2D image;
    uniform sampler2D lut;
    void main(){
        gl_FragColor = texture2D(image,fragTextCord);
    }
```

texture binding

```
        gl.useProgram(program);
        gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
        gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, imageTexture);
        gl.uniform1i(gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'image'), 0);
        gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE1);
        gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, lutTexture);
        gl.uniform1i(gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'lut'), 1);
```

both sampler2D image & lut render same image
using glview on react native

Comment: The problem is not reproducible. There is nothing wrong with you're code.

Comment: Maybe the problem is how you upload the data to the textures.